# DocuSign Anchor Tag Not on Same Page

Tags: docusignapi

I get the following error when placing Anchor Tags with a Y offset that will exceed the current page: TAB_OUT_OF_BOUNDS

Any suggestions on how I should handle such cases?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates, the resulting tab placement based off the anchor string, plus the addition of the specified Y offset to the anchor string is causing the tab to go off the page. Either modify the placement of the actual anchor string, or modify the Y offset you are providing for this particular tag to keep it on the page. Depending on your anchor string definitions/approach, you may need to special case this particular tag.

Answer (score 0):

In our case there were some fields at the very edge of a couple of the pages at the bottom causing the automated process to place (something?) outside the page boundaries.  We deleted the edge fields and it worked.

steps to reproduce:

1. upload our document
2. make a POST to envelopes with templateId specified in the body

in this case it's docusign's system messing up, not ours, and one should think that their system would be able to handle elements that are nearing the document boundaries, also the error message is vague as hell and makes you mistakenly think that there's a field in the source PDF called "Text 42" or "Text 53" or whatever that their system is assigning the I guess auto-generated off-page element.